# How make eye and nose bigger or smaller in opencv

Tags: opencv, dlib

i'm trying write an application make eye or nose bigger after selfphy with opencv and dlib , can you help me solve solution. Thank

Answer (score 1):

Detect the eye and nose position and then resize them. After that, blur the edge of the corrected area.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak the algorithm on [learnopencv.com](http://learnopencv.com) (search there for Delauney Triangulation). It creates a triangular mesh around the face landmarks. The mesh can thenn be distorted to create distortion effects as you want.